# Can I use PXDBScalar in a DAC Extension to query records from the same table?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm very new to the Acumatica world. The task I've been given is to add a field to SOLine that will show a sum of the quantity to be shipped within the next 30 days for the same inventory item on the given SOLine. The request was to have the field be available on a General Inquiry.

I've created a DAC Extension and figured that a field with the PXDBScalar should do it.

However, when I add the field to a Generic Inquiry, I get the same value for all of the records displayed.  It's as if when trying to query the same table it is using just one of the item's aggregate value instead of recalculating for each item/row displayed in the GI.

Is there something that I've done incorrectly in the PXDBScalar formula? Am I missing a reference to the current record?

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
  {

    #region DaysOf
    public class int_DaysInFuture : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Constant<int_DaysInFuture>
    {
      public int_DaysInFuture()
        : base(30)
        {
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region UsrSalesInNextThirtyDays
    public abstract class usrSalesInNextThirtyDays : PX.Data.IBqlField {}
    [PXDecimal(2)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Sales in next 30 days")]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search4<SOLine.openQty,
         Where<SOLine.inventoryID, Equal<SOLine.inventoryID>
          ,And< Where<DateDiff<SOLine.shipDate, Today, DateDiff.day>, LessEqual< int_DaysInFuture > >>
         >
        ,Aggregate<GroupBy<SOLine.inventoryID, Sum<SOLine.openQty>>>
                             >))]
    public virtual Decimal? UsrSalesInNextThirtyDays{ get; set; }
    #endregion


  }
}
```

So adding this field shows that the linking to InventoryItem was working as expected.

```
    #region UsrSalesInNextThirtyDays2
    public abstract class usrSalesInNextThirtyDaysTwo : PX.Data.IBqlField {}
    [PXDecimal(2)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Base Price")]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.basePrice,
         Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<SOLine.inventoryID>>
                             >))]
    public virtual Decimal? UsrSalesInNextThirtyDaysTwo{ get; set; }
    #endregion
```

So I tried adding an inner join to force the line to InventoryItem using the inventoryID field but the resulting query is still returning the sum of the last item returned as the sum result for all records in the result set.

```
    public abstract class usrSalesInNextThirtyDays : PX.Data.IBqlField {}
    [PXDecimal(2)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Sales in next 30 days")]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(
        Search5<SOLine.openQty,
            InnerJoin<InventoryItem,
                On<SOLine.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>,
            Where<DateDiff<SOLine.shipDate, Today, DateDiff.day>, LessEqual< int_DaysInFuture > >,
            Aggregate<Sum<SOLine.openQty>>
                             >))]
    public virtual Decimal? UsrSalesInNextThirtyDays{ get; set; }
```

I feel like I'm getting closer to forcing the DAC to generate the correct query but I'm not there yet.

Comment: Try to change `Where<SOLine.inventoryID, Equal<SOLine.inventoryID>` with `Where<SOLine.inventoryID, Equal<Current<SOLine.inventoryID>>`

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov - Adding Current<> as you suggested in your comment makes the G/I show an error message: Must declare the scalar variable "@P0". 
I wasn't sure I could reference Current<> in this context.  I considered whether there is a "this." method or a .Current method that applies to the SOLine object. Haven't tested that route yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference the table in a circular manner this way because of how the sub-queries are generated.

Comment: I ended up adding the fields to INSiteStatus which was a better fit for what we needed.